# How to send one log record to file and another to email using Python logging module with multiple handlers

Tags: python, python-logging

I am using the handlers TimeRotatingFileHandler and the SMTPHandler. I want to send the INFO messages to the file log and the exceptions the email. My setup is below:

```
import logging
from logging.handlers import TimeRotatingFileHandler
from logging.handlers import SMTPHandler

filelog_handler = TimedRotatingFileHandler(output_file, when='midnight')
filelog_handler.setFormatter(log_formatter)
filelog_handler.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
logger.addHandler(filelog_handler)


maillog_handler = SMTPHandler(mailhost=("email.address.org", 25),
                                         fromaddr="email@address.org",
                                         toaddrs="email@address.org",
                                         subject="send_err_email.py Message")
maillog_handler.setLevel(logging.INFO)
logger.addHandler(mail_log)
```

When I try this code it either sends to both file and email or it sends nothing. Can anyone help me pin point what I am doing wrong or if this is even possible. Your help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You currently have the SMTPHandler level set at INFO, so any event with level  INFO or higher will be handled by that handler.
You could replace your penultimate line with

```py
maillog_handler.setLevel(logging.ERROR)
```

so that only the ERROR and CRITICAL events are sent to the email.